# scikit-learn doesn't upgrade

Tags: python, scikit-learn, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my scikit-learn package. My current version is 1.0.2. I'm following the installation instruction here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#install-official-release

I am trying to upgrade by:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

This give the following messages in the terminal:

```
(nec37) xyz@VUSELNX-51ZNMR2:~/PycharmProjects/Xyz(master)$ pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /home/miniconda3/envs/nec37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/miniconda3/envs/nec37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/miniconda3/envs/nec37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.6 in /home/miniconda3/envs/nec37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1.0 in /home/miniconda3/envs/nec37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.7.3)
```

The same happens when I also use: `pip3 install -U scikit-learn`

The version still remains the same:

```
(nec37) xyz@VUSELNX-51ZNMR2:~/PycharmProjects/xyz(master)$ python -c "import sklearn;
 print(sklearn.__version__)"
1.0.2
```

How to upgrade it?

**Update** 
when I try:

> `pip install -I -U scikit-learn`

I get the following with no upgrade.

```
Installing collected packages: threadpoolctl, numpy, joblib, scipy, scikit-learn
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
hdbscan 0.8.28 requires cython>=0.27, which is not installed.
Successfully installed joblib-1.3.2 numpy-1.21.6 scikit-learn-1.0.2 scipy-1.7.3 threadpoolctl-3.1.0

(ims37) C:\Users\xyz\PycharmProjects\peakpickingdilemma>python -c "import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)"
1.0.2
```

Comment: it could be something else is depending on it so it doesn't upgrade, you can also use the `-I` flag to ignore the current install version, so `pip install -I -U scikit-learn`
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-I

Comment: Great suggestion. but it didn't update unfortunately. See the update section above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last version of scikit-learn to support Python 3.7, is 1.0.2, according to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/1.0.2/).

If you want to use a newer version of scikit-learn, you'll have to use a more recent version of Python.

(I usually go to the PyPI page of the package, select "Release history", then pick the most recent bug-fix release of every major.minor version, and scroll down to check the supported Python versions listed on the left-hand side. There's probably a better way, but this work for a quick scan of compatible releases.)

---

Perhaps an obvious note, but Python 3.7 was end-of-life mid 2023; there are no security fixes for it since then.

If you have to use Python 3.7, then expect you'll also have to use older package versions. You're essentially timetravelling to the past, and shouldn't expect newer packages to be able to be used.

Comment: This actually makes sense. I have been using python 3.7 for a while, and completely missed that may be dependent on upgrade. 
I updated python to 3.10 and the -I -U scikit-learn command updated to 1.4.1.post1.

I honestly don't know what post1 is. Is it some bugfix version?

Comment: The post1 release is a tiny update to 1.4.1, to limit the version of the NumPy dependency to be < 2.0. See https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/05dc38fecee9e325738e97822145385d0d2be259 .

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this statement once,

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

This should work.

Comment: This didn't work. 
```
(ims37) C:\Users\xyz\PycharmProjects\peakpickingdilemma>pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\xyz\miniconda3\envs\ims37\lib\site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1.0 in c:\users\xyz\miniconda3\envs\ims37\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\xyz\miniconda3\envs\ims37\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.1.0)
>> python -c "import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)"
1.0.2

```